# How to use html in custom wordpress block?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I am learning how to create a custom block in my wordpress theme.

The tutorial I am following says to add the html in the edit and save portions of the function like this:

```
(() => {
  
  registerBlockType('testblock', {    
    edit: props => {
      
      return (

        <div class="test-block">
            
          <RichText
              tagName="h2"
              className="test-name"
              placeholder={__("Enter Name…")}
              value={name}
              onChange={onChangeName}
          />
          
        </div>

      );
      
    }
  });

})();
```

But this give an error `SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'`

Answer (score 0):

Here are some steps to help you troubleshoot your issue:

1. Check the required dependancies have been imported:

```js
import { RichText } from '@wordpress/block-editor';
import { __ } from '@wordpress/i18n';
```

2. In JavaScript, `class` is a keyword so when applying classes, use `className` instead, eg `<div className="test-block">` (this is a very common error known to throw the same error message as in your question).
3. Is the attribute `name` is defined?
4. Does the function `onChangeName` exist?